# How to copy href atrribute by clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

after click a button `.btn`, I would like to copy a `href` atrribute on a clipboard.

here is the html source(clipboard.js recognize any type as button)

```
<a class="btn" href="#oops"><h1>Button</h1></a>
```

and below is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        new Clipboard(".btn", {
          text: function(trigger) {
            return $(trigger).getAttribute("href");
          }
        });
</script>
```

But I cannot make it work successfully. If someone would help me a second i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me

```js
new Clipboard('.btn', {
    text: function (trigger) {
        return trigger.getAttribute('href');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.4.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn" href="#oops"><h1>Button</h1></a>
```